# Wildfly URI for Websocket Client

Tags: java, websocket, wildfly, java-websocket, wildfly-11

Hey I am struggeling to connect my Client to my WebSocketEndpoint, I installed Wildfly 11 and it's running at

> localhost:9990

The problem is to connect to my Endpoint I need an URI which follows the rules

> "ws://"+hostname+":"+port+url

I know my url is defined at the Endpoint but how do I deploy my Endpoint to Wildfly and whats the URI then?

Comment: Port 9990 is for WildFly admin UI. For localhost you should use 8080.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a new [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) in your client where `hostname` is "localhost" and `port` is "9990", the JavaScript would be:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9990');
```

If your WebSocket server is not on the default route (`/`) you need to indicate the path:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9990/your/websocket/server');
```